# Can i freeze chocolate cream frosting / ganache?

Tags: freezing, chocolate

I made some chocolate cream frosting / ganache (basically just double / heavy cream with plain / bittersweet chocolate, melted and whipped up).

I ended up with twice as much as I need. Can I freeze it or will I simply have to eat it all (oh, the hardship)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may absolutely freeze chocolate ganache and most other chocolate preparations.  It should keep for up to a year without any noticeable change in quality.

Try to get a tight seal so it doesn't pick up other freezer odours.  Use a small freezer bag if you can, and maybe put that in a hard sealable container as well.  The freezing itself won't hurt the ganache at all but if it catches a whiff of those tuna casserole leftovers then you won't want to use it!

Comment: Thank you! (But I was slightly hoping you'd say I had to eat it all now :-))

Comment: @Vicky: I know it's tempting but it'll be even better once it goes inside some truffles and cream puffs.

Comment: When you take it out of the freezer, warm it slowly if possible and don't break the seal until it is at room temperature.