# How can I increase the shelf life of chocolate ganache?

Tags: storage-lifetime, chocolate, ganache

I'm testing out chocolate ganache recipes and they don't seem to have a long shelf life. The ganache begins to grow mold after the third week. Is there a specific percentage of cream, glucose, butter and chocolate that has to be used in order to minimize the growth of bacteria? I believe that there is too much water activity going on and therefore the ganache goes bad much more quickly. What am I doing wrong? Any insight would be amazing.

Comment: How are you using the chocolate ganache? Why do you need it to last more than 3 weeks? I'd be lucky to have anything last more than 1 week in my house if there was chocolate ganache on it.

Comment: Welcome to the site Sara! I know you specifically asked for shelf life, so I don't mean to be off-topic, but I found [this](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/10670/) question explaining that certain types of ganache and other chocolate products can be frozen. Your recipe's a bit different too, so I could be way off base, just looking for something that might be helpful to you!

Comment: What is the recipe you're using? Is your chocolate ganache set on a cake that you can't refrigerate?